# Запятая после "ах" и после "да"

Tags: запятая

Надо ли ставить запятые между этими словами?

*Ах, да, это же ты.*

Comment: @merry_2014, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3):

***АХ ДА, междометие (в начале предложения)***

Употребляется, когда говорящий неожиданно вспоминает о чём-то упущенном. Отделяется запятой от последующих слов. Между словами «ах и «да запятая обычно не ставится.

***Ах да, мои вещи. У меня нет вещей. Б. Полевой, Золото. Ах да, ведь вы с другого перрона! М. Булгаков, Бег. "Ах да, я забыл, - вдруг воскликнул он, -вам же мои картины не нравятся". Д. Гранин, Иду на грозу. "А когда мы уезжали на фронт, помнишь нашу теплушку?"-  "Ах да, конечно же, помню". Б. Окуджава, Будь здоров, школяр.***

Однако постановка запятой между словами «ах и «да возможна при наличии между ними интонационной паузы.

***А еще я люблю утятину, гусятину и индятину. Ах, да! Я всей душой люблю мороженое. В. Драгунский, Что любит Мишка. Что такое хорошее произошло? Ах, да: операция позади. И. Грекова, Перелом.***

***! Не смешивать с сочетанием междометия «ах и усилительной частицы "да".***

***Ах, да при чём тут сидение на скамейке! В. Гроссман, Жизнь и судьба. Ах, да неужто ли подобное возможно! В. Высоцкий, Палач.***

Answer (score 2):

Возможны два варианта:

(1) Ах да, это же ты. Частица АХ + утвердительное слово ДА.

(2) Ах, да это же ты. Междометие АХ, частица ДА